# I'm getting error in if() statement: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .//*[@id='p40021404_qty']

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
    if (big.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='p40021404_qty']")).getSize() != null){
        big.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-main']/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button")).click();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Quantity is less !!!");
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: use view source and try to see if there is a html element (a div may be)  with the id 'p40021404_qty' present in the screen. If not then you need to see why its not appearing.

Comment: You are calling `getSize()` on a reference that may be null. Also - I do not know Selenium - but does it throw that exception if there is no match for the xpath? In that case the exception would be expected and needs to be handled (try/catch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findElement` doesn't return `null`, it returns `WebElement` or throws `NoSuchElementException`. Also, `getSize()` will never be `null`.

You can use `findElements` and check if there are any elements in the list

```
List<WebElement> elements = big.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='p40021404_qty']"));
if (elements.getSize() > 0) {
    big.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-main']/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button")).click();
}
else {
    System.out.println("Quantity is less !!!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, the code worked  and i got the output as "Quantity is less !!!"                                                             List<WebElement> elements = big.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='p40021404_qty']"));
  if (elements.size() > 0) {
      big.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navbar-main']/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button")).click();
      System.out.println("Quantity is Validated !!!");
  }
  else {
      System.out.println("Quantity is less !!!");
  }

Answer (score 0):

Your condition throws exception because element is not present and you are not handling exceptions in this piece of code. You could find this element before checking it in if statement and watch out for exceptions, use try/catch as suggested in comments.